# Why use "\exists x" in set-builder notation?

Tags: quantifiers

[image]

Why is the \exists k used in this set-builder notation?

Comment: "The set of all integers $n$ such that there exists an integer $k$ allowing us to write $n = 2k$."

Comment: it is part of the definition of the set, set like $\{n\in \Bbb Z| (\forall k\in \Bbb Z)[n=2k]\}$ also make senses(though I defined an empty set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It always helps to read the mathematical notation with full sentences:

> The set of all such integers $n$ for which there exists some integer $k$ such that $n$ is equal to $2\cdot k$.

So, the "there exists" is vital in the definition of the set.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Thanks!